# How do statistical dependent inputs affect a multilayer perceptron neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

So the question basically is; does it matter what the inputs are of a MLP NN in the sense of input dependence. For example:

Input 1: A

Input 2: B

Input 3: A+B or A*B or any other function using A and B as variables.

For more basic regression models this sometimes makes a huge impact in how we interpret results or the functionality of the model in general. This lead me to question what happens in a general MLP NN.

Comment: it depends ${}{}$

Comment: It's reasonably common practice to generate "new" features using non-linear functions and/or combinations of features, if that's what you're asking.